# Finding first possibility

Tags: php, mysql

If I have this pattern to build ID's:

`CX00` where the 0's are replaceable with just a number.. but the following is already in use:

```
- CX00
- CX02
- CX04
- CX05
- CX07
- CX10
- CX11
- CX12
```

How can I easily find, either via PHP or MySQL the values `CX01, CX03, CX06, CX08, CX09, CX13+` as available values?

Comment: Why are you not just using e.g. an auto-increment field?

Comment: Since the company I'm making something for wants to re-use once deleted ID's.. If it only were that simple >_<

Comment: Then this is going to be tricky!  I don't think you can construct a query which says "give me the first thing not in the table".  I doubt you have many options other than to loop through each time.  (Perhaps you could do a one-off exercise which generates a list of unused IDs.)

Comment: So you can only have a maximum of 100 unique ids? as you dont mention CY00 increment, if so then you can grab all the current ids from the database and use the range(0,99) with combination of sprintf functions to iterate up till you match a missing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your data is stored, so I'll leave getting the IDs in an array.  Once you do, this will find the next available one.

```
<?php

function make_id($n) {
    $out = 'CX';
    if ($n < 10) $out .= '0';
    return $out . $n;
}

// Get these from some source
$items = array('CX00', 'CX02', 'CX04', 'CX05');
$id = make_id(0);

for($i=0; in_array($id, $items); $i++)
    $id = make_id($i);

echo $id;

?>
```

This is called a brute-force method, and if you have a lot of IDs there are probably more efficient ways.  With 100 maximum, there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 0):

In php simply count up through the ids using a for loop until you have found enough of the unused ids... how many total ids do you expect to have?